# Implicitly defined EntityClass does not work

Tags: wolfram-data-framework, entity

When studying how I can use the `Wolfram Data Framework` on a database on my private computer I found a curious problem. I created an `EntityStore` for my database and registered that. The entities with their properties are available. For example:

```
persoon=Entity["personen", 1]["voornaam"]
(* Lucas *)
```

Therefore, I expected that the following construction would give an entity class that contains at least one entity. But it remains unevaluated:

```
EntityClass["personen", "voornaam"->"Lucas"]
(* EntityClass[personen,voornaam->Lucas] *)
```

Of course, my first thought was that it has to do with my private database. But the following example from the documentation shows the same problem:

```
EntityClass["Aircraft", {"CruiseSpeed" -> Quantity[Interval[{550, 600}], "Miles"/"Hours"],
  "Height" -> Quantity[Interval[{75, 200}], "Feet"],
  "Wingspan" -> Quantity[Interval[{75, 80}], "Meters"]}]

(* EntityClass[Aircraft,{CruiseSpeed->(550to600)mi/h,Height->(75to200)ft,Wingspan->(75to80)m}] *)
```

I am running Mathematica 12.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 6, 2019).

It looks like the construction of an implicitly defined entity class with the function `EntityClass` does not work any more, anyway on my computer. Is this due to an installation failure on my system, or is it a more general problem?

Comment: This is as designed. `EntityClass` by itself does not evaluate. You will have to use `EntityValue` to extract values of various properties, or `EntityList` to get a list of individual entities.

Comment: @Leonid. It seems that I am becoming too old for Mathematica. Thanks for your explanation, very simple and clear. I think I have to delete this stupid question. Do you agree?

Comment: No, please don't delete it. It is an important point,  and it might be confusing also for others. I will return to this some time soon and expand the comment into a proper answer.